# Is it possible to double integrate my function over real numbers?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a fairly complicated function:

```
fxsbzs[x_, y_, z_, xs_, b_, zs_, A_] = 
     (y - b) (((x - xs)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - zs + A)^2)^(-(3/2)) 
            - ((x - xs)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - zs - A)^2)^(-(3/2))) 
   - (y + b) (((x - xs)^2 + (y + b)^2 + (z - zs + A)^2)^(-(3/2)) 
            - ((x - xs)^2 + (y + b)^2 + (z - zs - A)^2)^(-(3/2)));`
```

And I would like to have the definite symbolic double integral of `fxsbzs` with respect to `zs` and `xs`:

```
fabc[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_, c_, A_] = 
  Integrate[fxsbzs[x, y, z, xs, b, zs, A], {xs, -a, a}, {zs, -c, c}]
```

Is this possible (with `x, y, z, a, b, c, A` restricted to reals and `a, b, c, A > 0`) ?

---

I can solve the first integral with `Assumptions`:

```
fxsbc[x_, y_, z_, xs_, b_, c_, A_] = Integrate[fxsbzs[x, y, z, xs, b, zs, A], 
    {zs, -c, c}, 
    Assumptions -> {Element[{x, y, z, xs, b, c, zs, A}, Reals],
        (b + y) > 0 && (A + z - zs) > 0 && (-A + z - zs) > 0 && (-b + y) > 0 &&
        (x - xs) > 0 && a > 0 && c > 0 && b > 0 && A > 0}]
```

The result is a long function, which I can't integrate again with respect to `xs`. Every summand of `fxsbc` has basically this structure:

```
u/((xs + xs^2 + v) Sqrt[xs + xs^2 + w])
```

Since I can't solve the definite integral of this either, I think it's the crucial point:

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, u, v, w, a]
Integrate[u/((xs + xs^2 + v) Sqrt[xs + xs^2 + w]), {xs, -a, a}, 
    Assumptions -> {Element[{x, y, z, u, v, w, a}, Reals], 
    xs + xs^2 + w > 0 &&  u > 0 && v > 0 && w > 0 && a > 0}]
```

The indefinite integral gives a complex function:

> ```
> (1/(Sqrt[1 - 4 v] Sqrt[
>  v - w]))I u (Log[(I + I Sqrt[1 - 4 v] - 4 I Sqrt[1 - 4 v] w + 
>    2 I xs - 4 I v (1 + 2 xs) - 
>    4 Sqrt[1 - 4 v] Sqrt[v - w] Sqrt[w + xs + xs^2])/(2 Sqrt[
>    v - w] (1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 v] + 2 xs))] - 
>  Log[(2 Sqrt[1 - 4 v] Sqrt[w + xs + xs^2])/(
>  1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 v] + 2 xs) + (
>  I (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 v] - 4 Sqrt[1 - 4 v] w - 2 xs + 
>     v (4 + 8 xs)))/(2 Sqrt[v - w] (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 v] - 2 xs))])
> ```

Is it not possible to solve this integral in the real domain?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the Rule-based_Integrator of http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/ for Mathematica.
You will get a simpler structured Integral for your typical terms:

```
In[64]:= intR2 = Int[u/((xs + xs^2 + v) Sqrt[xs + xs^2 + w]), xs]

Out[64]= -((
 2 u ArcTan[(Sqrt[v - w] (1 + 2 xs))/(
   Sqrt[1 - 4 v] Sqrt[w + xs + xs^2])])/(Sqrt[1 - 4 v] Sqrt[v - w]))
```

Comment: OP here: Thanks for your help ***Akku14***! It works as it should. Off-Topic: Unfortunately while verifying my account, I seem to have created another one. So I can't mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @Axomul Please read http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts